# Why does my installer (MSI) fail when a new user is specified to be created and it attempts to reference that user in a SQL script during install?

Tags: sql, windows-installer, installshield

I currently have an installer I created using Installshield (Basic MSI) that allows the user to create a new user account in Windows. This user account is used by the installer in a SQL script that is executed by the the installer.

I'm experiencing a problem where the SQL script fails because the login doesn't exist yet so I'm asking when does this get created by the installer? Can I just move the IISQLServerInstall (the CA that actually executes the SQL scripts) to a later point in time so that it executes after the user is created? Any other ideas?

Comment: I want to make it clear as to what I am doing here. I'm currently using an installshield Basic MSI project to both allow new user creation (using the standard LogonInfoCreateUser dialog(s)) and also running some SQL scripts the call 'CREATE LOGIN' with this user information. The problem is that the SQL scripts fails because the user doesn't exist at the time the SQL scripts get executed. This works fine if the user uses an existing user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this inquiry to the Flexera community forums and got an answer today by one of the Installshield developers. It appears that this is a bug in Installshield 2011. He provided a hotfix which addresses this specific issue. You can read more about it and download the hotfix here: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=195894

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge you cannot use an user account in the same installation process which creates it.

This is because most installer actions get their information in the Immediate phase, when the installation script is created. In this phase the user account doesn't exist because it hasn't been created yet.

A common solution is to use a different package as a prerequisite for your main install. This package can install the user account you need.

Comment: That would result in a less than desirable user experience. They would be asked as a prereq for the user information before they ever even get to the rest of the installer settings. I've posted more information above in regards to exactly what I am doing so hopefully that can provide maybe another alternative path to what you have suggested.